# Django models, queryset using get_FOO_display()

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework

Consider a Django model that contains a CharField with choices.

I know I can do:

```
Product.objects.values('product_code').annontate(count=Count('product_code'))
```

But consider 'product_code' has choices, how can have the queryset return the result of get_product_code_display() and the count of them?

Comment: So does product.product_code.get_product_code_display() returns a portion of the tuple? The part which would be shown to a user in a form for example?  Are these choices static?

Comment: You could use a model manager for retrieving the "get_product_code_display" value that maps to the product code. The queryset above can be used to get the counts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with distinct.

Product.objects.values('product_code').distinct().annontate(count=Count('product_code'))

Comment: Distinct is meaningless.  You don't need it.  The issue is I don't want the product code returned I want the get_product_code_display() value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    result = []
for p in realdata.objects.filter(product='1').values_list(
                          'company', 'brand', 'created_by__username', 'ac_type'):
    choice = {k: v for k, v in realdata.type_choices}[p[-1]]
    result.append(list(p[:-1]) + [choice])
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205953/django-values-list-with-choices-field)